# The header sent by Postman is not received in the PHP script

Tags: php, nginx, httprequest, postman

I am sending a header along with a GET request to a PHP script but either Postman does not send the header or the PHP script does not receive it. I am using Nginx for the server (Apache2 gave almost the same result with api_token absent). I am not able to find what is wrong.

[image: Screenshot]

The server side PHP code is as follows:

```
<?php
 $headers =  getallheaders();
 foreach($headers as $key=>$val){
    echo $key . ': ' . $val . '<br>';
 }
?>
```

After checking from Postman console, it appears that the header is actually sent but not received inside PHP script for some reason.

[image: Screenshot2]

Comment: You could log out the request headers to the console to see if it’s getting sent - `console.log(pm.request.headers)` You’ll be able to see that output in the Postman Console. Might give you more ideas. Are you able to update the question with the server side code?

Comment: Danny, thanks. I added both the script and console output.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don’t think that you can use an underscore in the header name of a custom header as it’s a feature that’s disabled by default. More information can be found [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#underscores_in_headers)

You could test this out by removing this from the header name.

Comment: This is very strange... I used exactly that name (api_token) with a php framework called Laravel in past and it worked. Now it does not work with bare PHP and Phalcon. Like you said, removing underline solves the problem. Very much appreciated.

Comment: oh you are a life saver! I was struggling with this for past 2 hours trying to find why my custom headers were not being received by my bluehost server while it was working with no issues on my LAMP environment! As soon as I removed underscores from header keys it started working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be old thread;
I had same issue with new version of PostMan; Old version works fine (with USER and PW parameters).

***NOT A RESOLUTION AN ALTERNATIVE TO MOVE ON (before it is resolved at PostMan's end):***
An Odd and Quick solutions is to add a new variable in Header (e.g. username and password: which will be sent as HTTP_USERNAME and HTTP_PASSWORD)...
else you have to configure the .htaccess file, check PHP ini and WebServer (Apache/IIS)